# Regex Search&Replace in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

i try to find and replace everything between:
`<div id="foot">` and `<div id="foot_space">`

following regular expressions I've already tested:

```
<div id="foot">(.*?)<div id="foot_space">
#<div id="foot">(.*?)<div id="foot_space">#
```

The Code looks like:

```
<div id="foot">
Lorem Ipsum <span>Highlight</span>
</div>
<div id="foot_space"></div>
```

The remote and file search do not find any matches :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` probably does not match `\r` and `\n`. Try this:

```
(?s)<div id="foot">(.*?)<div id="foot_space">
```

or this:

```
<div id="foot">([\s\S]*?)<div id="foot_space">
```

The `(?s)` enables DOT-ALL, and `[\s\S]` matches *any* character. So `[\s\S]` and `(?s).` is the same in many regex implementations.

I'd also replace the literal spaces with a `\s+` if I were you.